# How to show a new row within ng-repeat based on click in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/gpGsKdhzdrPnCJ0A9Zdz?p=preview

HTML

```
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">

    <div class="rTable">
      <div class="rTableRow">
        <div class="rTableHead"><strong>Field1</strong></div>
        <div class="rTableHead">Field2</div>
        <div class="rTableHead">Field3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="rTableRow" ng-repeat="leaveApp in leaveAppColl">
        <div class="rTableCell">{{leaveApp.field1}}</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">{{leaveApp.field2}}</div>
        <div class="rTableCell"><a href="#">click</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.rTable {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.rTableRow {
  display: table-row;
}

.rTableHeading {
  display: table-header-group;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.rTableCell,
.rTableHead {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
}

.rTableHeading {
  display: table-header-group;
  background-color: #ddd;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.rTableFoot {
  display: table-footer-group;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.rTableBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.leaveAppColl=new Array();
    $scope.leaveAppColl[0]={field1:"abc",field2:"def",field3:"ghi"};
    $scope.leaveAppColl[1]={field1:"abc",field2:"def",field3:"ghi"};
    $scope.leaveAppColl[2]={field1:"abc",field2:"def",field3:"ghi"};
}
```

This is the code I have. I want that when the user clicks on a row, a new row should appear right beneath it, before the next row.

Here is what I am looking for : it's a pseudo example just to give an idea of what I am trying to achieve.

http://plnkr.co/edit/uAYnBsGZA2m9MOmyeXxc?p=preview

```
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">

    <h2>Phone numbers</h2>
    <h2>Phone numbers</h2>
    <div class="rTable">
      <div class="rTableRow">
        <div class="rTableHead"><strong>Field1</strong></div>
        <div class="rTableHead">Field2</div>
        <div class="rTableHead">Field3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="rTableRow">
        <div class="rTableCell">abc</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">abc</div>
        <div class="rTableCell"><a href="#">click</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rTableRow">
        <div class="rTableCell">abc</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">abc</div>
        <div class="rTableCell"><a href="#">click</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rTableRow">
        <div class="rTableCell">abc</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">abc</div>
        <div class="rTableCell"><a href="#">click</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: create a method to push a object to the leaveAppColl array on click

Comment: Use the [ng-click directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) and update the example to use a more current version of AngularJS. Examples that use v1.0.5 are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below steps

- add an `ng-click` event to row | `ng-click="addRow()"`
- pass index of row to `ng-click` handler | `ng-click="addRow($index)"`
- insert at specific index in array using [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). | `$scope.leaveAppColl.splice(index+1, 0, {field1:"",field2:"",field3:""});`

Ideally you shouldn't assign click event handler to rows because it may contains elements which are having their own event handlers.
So a better approach is, create a new column to add a new row or create a button i column header as shown in below **demo2**.

## Demo 1

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0WVKwC?p=preview)

## Demo 2

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mStcXl?p=preview)

Comment: thanks but I need to insert a table in between two rows. The values in this table are not in the same format as in the ng-repeat. For example, the leaveAppCollection may contain leaveApp values but the inserted row shows leaveapplication data which is not in the format of the value that is repetead on. I;m thinking I may have to use jQuery to manipulate the DOM

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html ng-app>
   <head>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js">      </script>
     <script src="script.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
 <body>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div class="rTable">
       <div class="rTableRow">
       <div class="rTableHead"><strong>Field1</strong></div>
       <div class="rTableHead">Field2</div>
       <div class="rTableHead">Field3</div>
   </div>
  <div class="rTableRow" ng-repeat="leaveApp in leaveAppColl">
    <div class="rTableCell">{{leaveApp.field1}}</div>
    <div class="rTableCell">{{leaveApp.field2}}</div>
    <div class="rTableCell"><a href="#" ng-click="addRow($index)">click</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**js:**

```
 function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.leaveAppColl=new Array();
    $scope.leaveAppColl[0]={field1:"abc",field2:"def",field3:"ghi"};
    $scope.leaveAppColl[1]={field1:"abc",field2:"def",field3:"ghi"};
    $scope.leaveAppColl[2]={field1:"abc",field2:"def",field3:"ghi"};
    $scope.addRow = function(index) {
      $scope.leaveAppColl.splice(index+1, 0,   { field1:"abc",field2:"def",field3:"ghi"});

 }
}
```

Plnkr link:

http://plnkr.co/edit/HGC1soLfjv1MSsjUjUux?p=preview

**splice method in array** is mainly use for adds/removes items to/from an array, and returns the removed item(s).

Format of splice is array.splice(index, how many, item1, ....., itemX)

Answer (score 0):

Just add array inside of your $scope.leaveAppColl array of every object. See below. Align css as per your need.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngSanitize']);

function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.leaveAppColl=new Array();
  $scope.leaveAppColl[0]={field1:"abc",field2:"def",field3:"ghi", pushHere:[]};
  $scope.leaveAppColl[1]={field1:"abc",field2:"def",field3:"ghi", pushHere:[]};
  $scope.leaveAppColl[2]={field1:"abc",field2:"def",field3:"ghi", pushHere:[]};
  
  $scope.addRow = function(id){    
    $scope.leaveAppColl[id].pushHere.push({field1:"New field "+id,field2:"New field "+id,field3:"New field "+id});     
  }
}
Ctrl.$inject =['$scope'];

app.controller('Ctrl', Ctrl);
```

```css
.rTable {
       display: table;
       width: 100%;
  }
  .rTableRow {
       display: table-row;
  }
  .rTableHeading {
       display: table-header-group;
       background-color: #ddd;
  }
  .rTableCell, .rTableHead {
       display: table-cell;
       padding: 3px 10px;
       border: 1px solid #999999;
  }
  .rTableHeading {
       display: table-header-group;
       background-color: #ddd;
       font-weight: bold;
  }
  .rTableFoot {
       display: table-footer-group;
       font-weight: bold;
       background-color: #ddd;
  }
  .rTableBody {
       display: table-row-group;
  }
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">

    <div class="rTable">
      <div class="rTableRow">
        <div class="rTableHead"><strong>Field1</strong></div>
        <div class="rTableHead">Field2</div>
        <div class="rTableHead">Field3</div>
      </div>
      <div style="" ng-repeat="leaveApp in leaveAppColl">
       <div class="rTableRow"> <div class="rTableCell">{{leaveApp.field1}}</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">{{leaveApp.field2}}</div>
        <div class="rTableCell"><a href="#" ng-click="addRow($index)">click</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rTableRow" ng-repeat="leave in leaveApp.pushHere"><div class="rTableCell">{{leave.field1}}</div><div class="rTableCell">{{leave.field2}}</div><div class="rTableCell">{{leave.field3}}</div></div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
<br>
 
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer to my question.

It can be found here:

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp

I wanted a new row to expand/collapse based on a click and `data-toggle=collapse` does just that.